# How can I do a subtraction with a two tape Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, arithmetic, turing-test

I have already made a Turing machine with just one tape that solves a subtraction between two numbers, but I trying to do the same but with TWO tapes.

As an example, how can I solve 4-2?

Taking account that 4 can be represented as 0000, 2 as 00 and the - as 1.

So, in this case the input will be 0000100.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the second number (from the second tape) to the first tape, and then use the already existing TM that subtracts the numbers